# Jhipster Microservices - Correct way to get UserId in Microservices?

Tags: jhipster

I am using JHipster's Gateway with JWT and I have a microservice.

When the rest call is forwarded from the gateway to the microservice, in the microservice business class, I want to get the user id of the authenticated user.

The reason for this is I want to save it in the DB with the entity so that one user's data can be completely separate from other user's data (and a user cannot update another user's data...etc..).

While I can get the logged in user name, I don't have the user id.

What is the correct approach to resolving this issue:

- call the gateway from the microservice ?

(this doesn't make too much sense to me as the gateway is calling the service and I'll want to know this info for most services).

- update the TokenProvider in the gateway to include a user Id ? (not certain how to do this). Is this the correct approach ?
- any other suggestions ?

Thanks,
Fergal.

Note: I see other similar questions.  This is not a duplicate question. Do not mark this a duplicate unless absolutely certain.  Note - I am using JWT

Comment: I would update the TokenProvider either by replacing the subject or adding a claim for the user id.

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou. I've posted my code so that might help others. Any feedback on the approach I taken is welcome.

Comment: Good work.Thanks for having published your code.. By the way you forgot a 't' in Authenication in SamAuthenicationToken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve this,  I added the user id in the token from the gateway to each microservice.

Here is how I solved this in the JHipster generated code:

**In Gateway**, add UserService to UserJWTController, and get the user id, and 
use it when you are creating a token.

```java
public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> authorize(@Valid @RequestBody LoginVM loginVM) {
    ...
    ...
    Optional<User> user = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(loginVM.getUsername());
    Long userId = user.get().getId();
    String jwt = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, rememberMe, userId);
    ...
```

add the claim to the token:

```java
  claim(USER_ID_KEY, userId)
```

note, I added this to Token Provider:

```java
  private static final String USER_ID_KEY = "userId";
```

and then in my **microservice's app**, I did this:

created a new class:

```java
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import java.util.Collection;

public class SamAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

private final Long userId;

public SamAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Long userId) {
    super(principal, credentials);
    this.userId = userId;
}

public SamAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Long userId) {
    super(principal, credentials, authorities);
    this.userId = userId;
}
}
```

and then I changed TokenProvider.getAuthentication to add the following lines:

```java
    Long userId = null;
    Object userIdObj = claims.get(USER_ID_KEY);
    if (userIdObj != null) {
        String userIdStr = userIdObj.toString();
        userId = Long.parseLong(userIdStr);
        log.debug("Claim--> {}", userId);
    } else {
        log.debug("No user id in token");
    }

    User principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities);
    return new SamAuthenticationToken(principal, token, authorities, userId);
```

and then I added a new method to SecurityUtils

```java
 public static Optional<Long> getUserId() {
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    return Optional.ofNullable(securityContext.getAuthentication())
        .map(authentication -> {
            if (authentication instanceof SamAuthenticationToken) {
                SamAuthenticationToken samAuthenticationToken = (SamAuthenticationToken) authentication;
                return samAuthenticationToken.getUserId();
            }
            return null;
        });
 }
```

and finally, I can now call this method from any Business class:

```java
    Optional<Long> userId = SecurityUtils.getUserId();
    if (userId.isPresent()) {
        log.info("User Id--->{}", userId.get());
    } else {
        log.info("No userId present.");
    }
```

Any feedback welcome.

Comment: Why would you choose the gateway for that?

Comment: @ddsultan - the gateway is the most appropriate place for this as it is something that a lot of the services behind the gateway need. By getting the gateway to do this, each service doesn't have do itself... as you can see, it's a very small change to the gateway but very useful.  I have used ISAM (IBM Security and Access Mgt) in a project and their reverse proxy does exactly this.

Comment: @fergal_dd thank you very much! Your implementation helped me a lot!!!

Comment: @RenanFranca - delighted to hear that... glad it helped you move ahead.